# How to implement a boolean function using just NAND or NOR logic Gates

Tags: digital-logic

How to implement function mentioned below  using Nand or Nor gate

Y=x1+ x2 x3+ x4'x5'

Where y is output
and x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 are inputs

Comment: This looks like a homework question.  You should explain what you do understand, what you don't understand and show your best attempt if you'd like to get the best help with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework with no attempted solution.

Comment: its question mentioned at chegg. X1=two nand gates having one input,x2 x3=two nand gates one having x2 and x3 as input and other one having single input (x2x3)',x4'*x5'=two nand gates one having two input nand gate and other is one input nand gate,two nor gate one having three input and one having one input.this case gates used are more.is there any other method to do this

Comment: i am newbie here. Actualliy i am not aware about rules here.i could not able to delete this question.I am trying on same lines but i put here to have more confidence about my way of solving.

Answer (score 2):

Both a NAND and a NOR, with both inputs connected together will give you a NOT.

A NOT on the output of a NAND will give you an AND, and likewise a NOR will give you an OR.

NOTs on all inputs of a NAND will give you an OR, and likewise a NOR will give you an AND.

You can now make all the familiar logic functions from just a NAND or NOR prototype. Now implement the expression in the straightforward way.

Answer (score -1):

NOR = (x+y)'
Consider setting the first argument x of  x NOR y to FALSE, then NOR becomes (FALSE+y)' and by boolean algebra FALSE+y = y thus FALSE NOR y = NOT y. So setting either argument of NOR to FALSE yields the NOT function. Then apply the NOT function to NAND and you get AND. Similarly, apply the NOT function to NOR and you get OR.

So for your function an un-reduced composition would look something like:

x4'x5' = FALSE NOR ((FALSE NOR x4) NAND (FALSE NOR x5))

x2x3 = FALSE NOR (x2 NAND x3)

For clarification: a + b = FALSE NOR (a NOR b)

x2x3 + x4'x5' = FALSE NOR ((FALSE NOR (x2 NAND x3)) NOR (FALSE NOR ((FALSE NOR x4) NAND (FALSE NOR x5))))

Finally:

x1 + x2x3 + x4'x5' = FALSE NOR ((x1) NOR (FALSE NOR ((FALSE NOR (x2 NAND x3)) NOR (FALSE NOR ((FALSE NOR x4) NAND (FALSE NOR x5))))))

For further reduction, notice x4'x5' = (x4 + x5)' = x4 NOR x5 by De Morgan's Law:

So x1 + x2x3 + x4'x5' = FALSE NOR ((x1) NOR (FALSE NOR ((FALSE NOR (x2 NAND x3)) NOR (x4 NOR x5))))

See the following reference for more information on universal logic gates: 
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/universal-logic-gates/

Comment: Please don't provide answers to homework questions without getting the OP to do some significant work. I, for one, do not want this to turn in to a homework solving service.

Comment: I give OP benefit of the doubt, perhaps OP was working through some text examples and just needed clarification. I remember first coming across this topic and it was not explained well in a problem solving context. For this type of problem seeing the method of function construction is key to understanding enough to solve the whole class of problems.